# MapReduce : Can Mapper and Reducer share variable?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using `Java`, `Hadoop` for `MapReduce`.

Input (`txt` file):

```
doc1    apple pizza apple
doc2    pear apple
doc3    cookie noodle apple
doc4    pizza milk
.
.
.
```

`Mapper` read each line of above text file and emit `(word, 1)` . But since `Reducer` should knows how many each word appear in WHOLE docs. For example, in case of "apple", it occurs at doc1, doc2, doc3 so '3' is needed in `Reducer`.

What I'm thinking about is like this:
Since `Reducer` start to run after all `Mapper`'s job are done, `Mapper` could count increase the value of   `HashMap` every time it emits `(word, 1)`. For example, when `Mapper` read `doc1` line, it makes whole contents as unique word (=> apple pizza). And every time it emits `(word, 1)`, say `(apple, 1)`, do `hashMap['apple'] ++`.

And after all `Mapper`'s jobs are done, `Reducer` access this `HashMap` so that it can use how many times each word appears in whole docs.

I have read about [How to share a variable in Mapper and Reducer class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196097/how-to-share-a-variable-in-mapper-and-reducer-class), but I want to get advices from you guys.

p.s Sorry for poor english but I'm not native. Comment please if you can not understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand exactly what you are doing here.

What is the goal of this ?
If it is to count how many times you have every word in all your records it is going to work like this:

Mapper:

```
function map(){
  String[] arr = line.split(" ");
  foreach(String word : arr){
    context.write(word,1)
  }
}
```

After the map all your keys will be sorted by key, and grouped together.
This is very important feature.

Example:

```
 Mapper:
    doc1 will produce:
    apple 1
    pizza 1
    apple 1
```

After mapper the docs will be grouped by key:
apple => [1,1]
pizza => [1]

Reducer:

```
function reduce(apple, [1,1]){

        count=0;
        foreach(value in values) do:
          count++
        done

        context.write(key,count) ; //Here you will have the number of apples 
    in all your docs 
}
```